# Date Increment Using Autohotkey

Tags: date, scripting, autohotkey

I'm looking for a way to set an arbitrary date, and every time I press a key it will print the day after it (tomorrow).

```
global jDate = "June 1, 1986"
^+z::
    ;Output our date in LongDate format
    FormatTime, TimeString, %jDate%, LongDate
    SendInput, %TimeString%

    ;Increment the date by a single day
    jDate += 1, Days
Return
```

Unfortunately, it the code keeps starting jDate as today's current date/time rather than the past date I specify in the initial variable assignment. Not sure why. The incrementing works fine, it just increments starting from todays date rather that the 1986 date.

Answer (score 0):

`FormatTime` is expecting any date/time input to be in the ["YYYYMMDD..." format](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FormatTime.htm). Since what you've assigned to *jDate* doesn't fit that criterion, it assumes it's invalid and uses today's date. To make it work how you expect, just modify your *jDate* input.

```
jDate := "19860601" ; 1986 -> YYYY, 06 -> MM, 01 ->DD
```

A couple of things to note: (1) `global` is not needed in this context; (2) I would recommend getting out of the habit of assigning variables using the `=` comparator (use `:=` assignment operator instead). It only works for [legacy](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Intro) reasons but generates more confusion than it's worth. In the context that you're using it, the quotes would need to be removed.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still uses today's date. Not sure why.